# TypeError: _data__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I am new in react and trying to learn how array works with component using map function but I got this error recently and I don't have any idea what it is and how to solve it

I have tried reading many blog related to this but none of them are helping me here.

My react code is as follow:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Text from './Text.js';
import questions from './data';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let questionsAnswer = questions.map(item => <Text question={item.question} answer ={item.answer}/>);

return <div>
  hi
    </div>;
      }
}

export default App;
```

my array file is as follow:

```js
const questions = [
    {
        id:"1",
        question:"How are you ?",
        answer:"I am fine"
    },
    {
        id:"2",
        question:"Where do you live?",
        answer:"Kathmandu"
    },
    {
        id:"3",
        question:"How old are you ?",
        answer:"I am 20yrs"
    },
    {
        id:"4",
        question:"Are you a male?",
        answer:"yes I am"
    }
]
```

Comment: you should be using a default export for your questions... `export default [ {...} ]`

Answer (score 2):

Your code don't see exactly your question variable. Maby you should use export in your file "data" to export your questions.

Comment: Oh my god all these just for a  common piece of line How  can I miss that...Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have not export questions variable.
just write below the array ends

```
export default questions;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the `export default questions` expression at the end of your array script

Answer (score 0):

You need to export you questions before importing them, you can do it following ways.

```
export default questions = []
```

and then you can import it like

```
import questions from './data';
```

or you can use

```
export questions = []
```

then you should be able to import it like this

```
import {questions} from './data';
```